# Equivalent of CGFloat.maximum in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In Swift I can do this:

```
let z = CGFloat.maximum(20.0, 50.0) // z = 50.0
```

Tried to convert it to Objective-C:

```
CGFloat z = [CGFloat maximum:20.0, 50.0]; // Also tried (CGFloat *)
```

But getting a compilation error:

> Receiver type 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') is not an Objective-C class

To simplify example I used 2 constants, but in reality function will receive 2 CGFloat variables, if it matters.

So how can I get maximum between 2 CGFloats in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGFloat z = MAX(20, 50);
```

CGFloat is not an object, so there is no `*` and no methods.